# Input popup window for input into interactive python game

Tags: python, input, popup, pygame

I am a newcomer to Python and is in need of programming a simple game that requires the user to input some values into an input screen (afterwhich the Python code would do something with that input). What is the best API to use in this case? I know that pygame gives a very nice GUI on which users can interact with object on the screen but I do not know if this would be the best thing to use in a formal project. Otherwise, I've heard about Tkinter and various other applications but really have no idea what would be best.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a pretty subjective question. Keep in mind that pygame is typically used for graphics, while something like tkinter or GTK are more for developing user interfaces that are geared toward data entry. If all you need are typed inputs and outputs, pygame might be overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from Tkinter import *

class MyDialog:

    def __init__(self, parent):

        top = self.top = Toplevel(parent)

        Label(top, text="Value").pack()

        self.e = Entry(top)
        self.e.pack(padx=5)

        b = Button(top, text="OK", command=self.ok)
        b.pack(pady=5)

    def ok(self):

        print "value is", self.e.get()

        self.top.destroy()


root = Tk()
Button(root, text="Hello!").pack()
root.update()

d = MyDialog(root)

root.wait_window(d.top)
root.mainloop()
```

[Sauce](http://www.pythonware.com/library/tkinter/introduction/dialog-windows.htm)